# How to handle double quotes inside field values with csv module?

Tags: python, csv

I'm trying to parse CSV files from an external system which I have no control of.

- comma is used as a separator
- when cell contains comma then it's wrapped in quotes and all other quotes are escaped with another quote character.
- (my problem) when cell was not wrapped in quotes then all quote characters are escaped with another quote nonetheless.

Example CSV:

> qw""erty,"a""b""c""d,ef""""g"

Should be parsed as:

```
[['qw"erty', 'a"b"c"d,ef""g']]
```

However, I think that Python's csv module does not expect quote characters to be escaped when cell was not wrapped in quote chars in the first place.
`csv.reader(my_file)` (with default `doublequote=True`) returns:

```
['qw""erty', 'a"b"c"d,ef""g']
```

Is there any way to parse this with python csv module ?

Comment: Why not replace all instances of `'""'` inside of double quotes with `'\\"'`? Then the `csv` reader should be able to work normally.

Comment: your quote character and escape character are the same?

Comment: @JackManey "inside of double quotes" fragment was unnecessary, but overall I think it will work provided I escape all '\' characters as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Following on @JackManey comment where he suggested to replace all instances of `'""'` inside of double quotes with `'\\"'`.

Recognizing if we are currently inside of double quoted cells turned out to be unnecessary and we can replace all instances of `'""'` with `'\\"'`.
[Python documentation says](https://docs.python.org/3.1/library/csv.html#csv.Dialect.escapechar):

> On reading, the escapechar removes any special meaning from the following character

However this would still break in the case where original cell already contains escape characters, example: `'qw\\\\""erty'` producing `[['qw\\"erty']]`. So we have to escape the escape characters before parsing too.

Final solution:

```
with open(file_path, 'rb') as f:
  content = f.read().replace('\\', '\\\\').replace('""', '\\"')
  reader = csv.reader(StringIO(content), doublequote=False, escapechar='\\')
  return [row for row in reader]
```

Answer (score 0):

as @JackManey suggests, after reading the file, you can replace the two-double-quotes with a single-double-quote.

```
my_file_onequote = [col.replace('""', '"') for col in row for row in my_file]
```

Comment: This will fail with "ab""cd,ef" returning 2 cells however @JackManey got it almost right I think.