# Python csv with double quotes doesnt separate in column

Tags: python, csv, quote

I am having some trouble with reading a csv file in python
I have my data, but some columns have double quotes inside, for example:

```
First field First Row,This is the second field in the first row
First Field Second Row,This is the "second" field in the second row
```

So, my csv reader is as follows:

```
with open('data.csv', encoding="utf-8") as csv_file:
csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=',')
```

And the thing is, when i go through the rows, when it checks on the second line, for some reason it doesn't split the column on the ",".
So i am getting this when i print each row:

```
['First field First Row' , 'This is the second field in the first row']
['First Field Second Row,This is the "second" field in the second row']
```

Any fix for this to be correctly split?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hope following link would help you.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28725898/how-to-handle-double-quotes-inside-field-values-with-csv-module

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By defaults, double quotes are special and are used to quote fields. You must tell the reader that they are not special in your file:

```
with open('data.csv', encoding="utf-8") as csv_file:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=',', quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE)
```

Comment: I have tried it but i get this now :
['"First Field Second Row,This is the """"second""""" field in the second row']
:/

Comment: @Rever92: is what you have showed in the question really the way the csv files appears in notepad or vi? A CSV is a **text** file, and we have to see it in a raw text editor to know how to process it.

Comment: i have just checked it, and it seems to work now with your fix, i think i had something messed up. Thank you so much!