# What's a straightforward way to split a string on 'top level' only, regarding quotes and parentheses?

Tags: python, csv, parsing, split

I want to provide a function which takes a comma-separated string and splits it on separators, similar to `str.split()` but keeping (potentially nested) quoted and parenthesized parts.
Examples include comma-separated key-value pairs (`a=b,c=d`) but also comma-separated shell commands which might include the separator or even quote characters you could use to write a simple regex.

To avoid writing a fully-fledged parser my first idea was to use the `csv` module (see [How to handle double quotes inside field values with csv module?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28725898/how-to-handle-double-quotes-inside-field-values-with-csv-module)) but I failed using it even for simple cases e.g.:

```
>>> s = "a='[1,2,3]',c=d"
>>> list(csv.reader([s], delimiter=',', quotechar="'"))  # expected: ["a='[1,2,3]'", "c=d"]
[["a='[1", '2', "3]'", 'c=d']]
```

and I didn't try with more complex stuff like `a='[1,"3,14",3]',c="[4,5,6]"`.

Is there an easy way to either tame `csv.reader` to split the above string into `['a=..', 'c=..']` or even better to use some built-in string processing capability?

Comment: What's the specification for the string? Do we need to support escaping quotes so they're not actual quotes, etc.? (IOW: no, there's no simple, generic way.)

Comment: I guess an approach which successfully splits `a='[1,"3,14",3]',c="[4,5,6]"` into `a='[1,"3,14",3]'` and `c="[4,5,6]"` would be a good starting point. I.e stack counting different types of quotes would be a good starting point. Close to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4284991/parsing-nested-parentheses-in-python-grab-content-by-level but I need the top level separators only..

Answer (score 1):

Well, **for your particular data**, you can cheat a bit since if you squint, it looks like what kwargs for a Python call would look like, so wrap it in a call expression and parse the AST.

```
import ast

target = """
a='[1,"3,14",3]',c="[4,5,6]"
"""

tree = ast.parse(f"XXX({target.strip()})", "...", "eval")

print({kw.arg: ast.unparse(kw.value) for kw in tree.body.keywords})
```

prints out

```
{'a': '\'[1,"3,14",3]\'', 'c': "'[4,5,6]'"}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a function that works for me and accepts a custom delimiter:

```py
def smart_split(string: str, delimiter: str = ",") -> Iterable[str]:
    """Like str.split but takes quotes and parenthesis into account
    >>> list(smart_split("(=,),'a=x',\\"b=y\\""))
    ['(=,)', "'a=x'", '"b=y"']
    """
    splits: list[int] = []
    closers: list[str] = []
    parenthizers = {'"': '"', "'": "'", "[": "]", "(": ")"}
    for i, char in enumerate(string):
        if char == delimiter and not closers:
            splits.append(i)
        elif closers and char == closers[-1]:
            closers.pop()
        elif char in parenthizers:
            closers.append(parenthizers[char])
    start = 0
    for pos in splits:
        yield string[start:pos]
        start = pos + 1
    yield string[start:]
```

Be warned though, there is no consistency check and no support for escaped parenthesis or whatsoever.